# Transfer all tables from a schema to other schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema

I have two schema. Schema1 and Schema2

How would I transfer all the tables from schema1 to schema2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute this for all of the tables:

```
alter schema2
transfer schema1.table1;
```

To programmatically get the statements to execute:

```
declare
    @SourceSchemaName sysname,
    @DestinationSchemaName sysname,
    @AlterStatements varchar(max);

set @SourceSchemaName = 'NewSchema';
set @DestinationSchemaName = 'HumanResources';
set @AlterStatements = '';

select
    @AlterStatements +=
        'alter schema ' + quotename(@DestinationSchemaName) + 
        ' transfer ' + quotename(schema_name(schema_id)) + '.' + quotename(object_name(object_id)) +
        char(13) + char(10)
from sys.tables
where schema_id = schema_id(@SourceSchemaName);

print @AlterStatements;
```

Comment: I have a thousand tables.

Comment: I edited my answer to show code to generate the `ALTER` statements.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming destination schema is empty:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER SCHEMA Schema2 TRANSFER Schema1.' 
  + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';' FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE s.name = N'Schema1';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If the destination schema is not empty, you'll need additional handling for conflicts.